# calling variables for rule individually and adding an independent environment for a specific rule

Tags: python, function, wildcard, expand, snakemake

I need to run a snakemake rule in the cluster, therefore for some rules, I need some tools and library needed to e loaded whereas, these tools are independent/ exclusive to other rules. I this case how can I specify these in my snakemake rule. For example, for `rule score` I need to `module load r/3.5.1` and `export R_lib =/user/tools/software` currently, I am running these lines separately in the command line before running snakemake. But it would be great if there is a way to do it within the rule as `env`.

2. Question,

I have a rule as following,

```
rule score:
    input:
        count=os.path.join(config['general']['paths']['outdir'], 'count_expression', '{sample}.tsv'),
        libsize=os.path.join(config['general']['paths']['outdir'], 'count_expression', '{sample}.size_tsv')
    params:
        result_dir=os.path.join(config['general']['paths']['outdir'], 'score'),
        cancertype=config['general']['paths']['cancertype'],
        sample_id=expand('{sample}',sample=samples['sample'].unique())
    output:
        files=os.path.join(config['general']['paths']['outdir'], 'score', '{sample}_bg_scores.tsv', '{sample}_tp_scores.tsv')
    shell:
        'mkdir -p {params.result_dir};Rscript {config[general][paths][tool]} {params.result_dir} {params.cancertype} {params.sample_id} {input.count} {input.libsize}'
```

My actual behavior for the above code snippet is:

```
shell:
        mkdir -p /cluster/user/snakemake_test/results_april30/score;Rscript /cluster/home/user/Projects/R_scripts/scoretool.R /cluster/user/snakemake_test/results_april30/score DMC GNMS4 MRT5T /cluster/projects/test/results/exp/MRT5T.tsv /cluster/projects/test/results/Exp/MRT5T.size.tsv
```

Whereas, the expected behavior is:

```
shell:
        mkdir -p /cluster/user/snakemake_test/results_april30/score;Rscript /cluster/home/user/Projects/R_scripts/scoretool.R /cluster/user/snakemake_test/results_april30/score DMC MRT5T /cluster/projects/test/results/exp/MRT5T.tsv /cluster/projects/test/results/Exp/MRT5T.size.tsv
```

and for the second sample,

```
shell:
        mkdir -p /cluster/user/snakemake_test/results_april30/score;Rscript /cluster/home/user/Projects/R_scripts/scoretool.R /cluster/user/snakemake_test/results_april30/score DMC GNMS4 /cluster/projects/test/results/exp/GNMS4.tsv /cluster/projects/test/results/Exp/GNMS4.ize.tsv
```

I need the variable  `sample_d` `['GNMS4', 'MRT5T']` should be taken separately, not together in one shell command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question: You can put whatever `module load` or `export` commands you like in the `shell` section of a rule.

Regarding your second question, you should probably not use `expand` in the `params` section of your rule. In `expand('{sample}',sample=samples['sample'].unique())` you are actually not using the value of the `sample` wildcard, but generating a list of all unique values in `sample['sample']`. You probably just need to use `wildcards.sample` in the definition of your shell command instead of using a `params` element.

If you want to run several instances of the `score` rule based on possible values for `sample`, you need to "drive" this using another rule that wants the output of `score` as its input.

Note  that to improve readability, you can use python's multi-line strings (triple-quoted).

To sum up, you might try something like this:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand(
            os.path.join(
                config['general']['paths']['outdir'],
                'score',
                '{sample}_bg_scores.tsv',
                '{sample}_tp_scores.tsv'),
            sample=samples['sample'].unique())

rule score:
    input:
        count = os.path.join(
             config['general']['paths']['outdir'],
             'count_expression', '{sample}.tsv'),
        libsize = os.path.join(
             config['general']['paths']['outdir'],
             'count_expression', '{sample}.size_tsv')
    params:
        result_dir = os.path.join(config['general']['paths']['outdir'], 'score'),
        cancertype = config['general']['paths']['cancertype'],
    output:
        files = os.path.join(
            config['general']['paths']['outdir'],
            'score', '{sample}_bg_scores.tsv', '{sample}_tp_scores.tsv')
    shell:
        """
        module load r/3.5.1
        export R_lib =/user/tools/software
        mkdir -p {params.result_dir}
        Rscript {config[general][paths][tool]} {params.result_dir} {params.cancertype} {wildcards.sample} {input.count} {input.libsize}
        """
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [`onstart`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#onstart-onsuccess-and-onerror-handlers) would work I think. Note that dryruns don't trigger this handler, which is acceptable in your scenario.

```
onstart:
   shell("load tools")
```

2. Simple bash `for` loop should solve the problem. However, if you want each sample to be run as a separate rule, you would have to use sample name as part of `output` filename.

```
shell:
   '''
   for sample in {param.sample_id}
   do
      your command $sample
   done
   '''
```

Comment: Thanks but onstart does not help in my case. however, piping the module load at shell: did help.